# ASP.NET 5 Identity customize AspNetUserRoles

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I'm using ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 and Identity. In Identity the AspNetUserRoles table hold the roles the users has.

I need to modify AspNetUserRoles so I also include information about Organization, so a user have different roles in different organizations. So I need to do a call like this:

```
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUsr, "Purchase", OrganizationUnit24);
```

Is this possible to fix in any way

Comment: You may want to look into the "groups" feature available in Identity.

Comment: Have a look at the UnicornStore sample on GitHub. https://github.com/rowanmiller/UnicornStore/tree/master/UnicornStore/src/UnicornStore/Models/Identity